# getting trouble in displaying too long text in flutter pdf generating

Tags: flutter, pdf, flutter-layout, pdf-generation, flutter-dependencies

**Printing Pdf**

I'm going to generate a pdf file with flutter printing package, but I'm getting trouble with Text widget. When passing a text that's too long; it can't display it in one page or the remaining space in the page.

what I did:

1. set softWrap as true.
2. set tightBounds as true
3. set overflow as pw.TextOverflow.span
4. although I looked for an answer, I did not get any result.

```
pw.Text(
                'متن نامه:'
                ' بررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی'
                ' بررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی'
                ' بررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی'
                ' نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص '
                ' نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص '
                ' نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص '
                'پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی'
                'پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی'
                'پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی'
                'پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی'
                ' نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص'
                'پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی'
                'پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی'
                'پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی'
                'پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی'
                ' نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص'
                ' نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص'
                ' نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص'
                ' پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی'
                ' پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی'
                'پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی'
                'پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی'
                'پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی'
                'پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی'
                ' نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص'
                ' نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص'
                ' پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی'
                ' پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی'
                'پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی'
                'پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی'
                'پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی'
                'پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی'
                ' نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص'
                ' نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص'
                ' نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص'
                ' پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی'
                ' پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهبررسی'
                ' نواقص پروژهبررسی نواقص پروژهمتن نامه: بررسی نواقص پروژه',
                textDirection: pw.TextDirection.rtl,
                overflow: pw.TextOverflow.span,
                softWrap: true,
                tightBounds: true,
                style: pw.TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                  font: myFont,
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: Can't you split the text in different widgets, like multiple `Text` (or `RichText`) inserted in a single `Column`? That should allow the package to adapt the long text to multiple pages. You can look at the [demo](https://davbfr.github.io/dart_pdf/#/) under the 'document' section (you can see the code by pressing the '<>' button in the bottom right of the page)

Comment: @il_boga 
I get data from server and it's continuous text.

Comment: Ugh, that might be a problem. The package can't split a `Widget` in order to change page, so you have to think of something to split the incoming text yourself. The text has no new line or carriage feed characters? Something you can split on the text in order to create different widgets?

Comment: @il_boga I split text with space and then display each item as Text widget in and then through them all in wrap widget. But now I have another problem with direction of page...

Comment: Can you upload an image about your output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, create separate widgets and write those widgets inside Multi Page or you can directly call your text widget inside Multi Page, For me the lengthy texts are working and also breaking the line properly and displaying on the next page.
`

```
Class PdfGenerate{
static Future<Uint8List> generate({}) async{
final pdf = Document();
pdf.addPage(
MultiPage(
build: (context) => [
/*Here you can write your text, You better use a paragraph widget, it'll break the like properly*/
Paragraph(""),
]
)
);
return pdf.save();
}
}
```

`